Variable Calculation
there is a variable I need to calculate during FF++ code as per the attached equation.
kindly note that Ne,p,n and We,p,n and El are finite element spaces
I = int2d(Th)(2*pi*x*q*(-mue*Neold + mup*Npold - mun*Nnold)*((E1L*E1)+(E2L*E2)));
I = I/abs(Vapp);

